# Snakemake: RuntimeError stack trace missing when using Python fileConfig()

Tags: python, logging, snakemake

I have a snakefile with one rule which imports a local Python script and then raises a `RuntimeError`. When I run the snakefile, the stack trace for the `RuntimeError` is not shown. The code and snakemake output are shown below.

```
// test.snakefile
rule test_rule:
    run:
        from test import hello
        print(hello)
        raise RuntimeError('raising error')
```

```
// test.py
import logging
import os
from logging.config import fileConfig

log_file_path = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)), 'logging_config.ini')
fileConfig(log_file_path)

hello = 'hello'
```

snakemake output:

```
...
[Mon Jan 13 14:45:54 2020]
rule test_rule:
    jobid: 0

Job counts:
    count   jobs
    1   test_rule
    1
hello
Shutting down, this might take some time.
Exiting because a job execution failed. Look above for error message
```

However, if I comment out the line `fileConfig(log_file_path)` in `test.py` and run snakemake, the RuntimeError stack trace is printed as expected:

```
Error in rule test_rule:
    jobid: 0

RuleException:
RuntimeError in line 5 of /my-dir/test.snakefile:
raising error
  File "/my-dir/test.snakefile", line 5, in __rule_test_rule
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/concurrent/futures/thread.py", line 56, in run
Exiting because a job execution failed. Look above for error message
```

Anyone know why this occurs?

EDIT:
logging_config.ini

```
[loggers]
keys=root

[handlers]
keys=stream_handler

[formatters]
keys=formatter

[logger_root]
level=INFO
handlers=stream_handler

[handler_stream_handler]
class=handlers.TimedRotatingFileHandler
level=DEBUG
formatter=formatter
args=('/tmp/experiments.log', 'midnight')

[formatter_formatter]
format=%(asctime)s %(name)-12s %(levelname)-8s %(message)s
```

Comment: Can you show the contents of `logging_config.ini`? Wondering if `stderr` gets redirected to some file specified in the config.

Comment: Shouldn't hello also be printed?

Comment: @Maarten-vd-Sande Yes, hello is printed above the stack trace, I just didn't copy it in the post.

Comment: @ManavalanGajapathy Edited the post to include `logging_config.ini`!

Comment: Looks like this error is due to logging setup and not snakemake's. I think if you executed the code in `run` section as a separate python script, you would have the same problem. Did you check `/tmp/experiments.log` to see if error messages get redirected there? Also, you may need to add [`logger=logging.getLogger()` after `fileConfig()`](https://docs.python-guide.org/writing/logging/#example-configuration-via-an-ini-file).

Comment: @ManavalanGajapathy I executed the code in the `run` section in a separate Python script and got the expected stack trace. The log doesn't have the error messages, and adding `logger=logging.getLogger()` did not change anything. I also tried pasting the code from `test.py` into the `run` section instead of importing it, but I got a `RuleException:
KeyError in line 8 of /my-dir/test.snakefile:
'formatters'`, which was the `fileConfig` line in the `run` section. Not sure what that means, but I'll try playing around with the log file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue has to do with how `logging` module was defined in `test.py` and how they were imported in `Snakefile`. Following setup should work. Please note comments inside code block for description of modifications.

*test.py*

```py
import logging
import os
from logging.config import fileConfig

fileConfig('logging_config.ini')
logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)   # assigns to "logger", through which logs are passed. 
logger.info('test.py debug msg')   # example log message

hello = 'yo yo yo'
```

*Snakefile*

```py
rule test_rule:
    run:
        from test import hello, logger.   # imports both hello and logger
        print(hello)
        print (logger)

        logger.exception("Exception occurred")   # error log that would capture stack traces, if any. No stack trace in this example.
        raise SystemExit(1)     # exits with non-zero error
```

*logging_config.ini* - same as posted in questions.

In this setup, variable `hello` and class `logger` get imported into rule `test_rule`, and their logging output gets written into file `/tmp/experiments.log`, as configured in `logging_config.ini`.